# PHP Convert Windows-1251 to UTF 8

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, windows-1251

I have a small html code and I need to convert it to UTF-8.
I use this `iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8", $html);`

All text converts correctly, but if text for example in tag `<i>...</i>`, then it don't convert text and I see somethig like this `РџРѕРєР°Р·Р°С‚СЊ РјРЅ`

Comment: please provide the string that you're trying to convert.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you have access to the Multibye package, you can try it. See the PHP page here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

```
$html_utf8 = mb_convert_encoding($html, "utf-8", "windows-1251");
```

Answer (score 1):

You know, message like `РџРѕРєР°Р·Р°С‚СЊ РјРЅ` you see if
encoding for page is `windows-1251`, but text encoded in `utf-8`.
I saw this problem in one of my project, so just change change encoding for page in `utf-8` and this text will shown correctly.

Let me take you some examples:
if page in `utf-8`, but text in `windows-1251` you wil see something like this:
`???? ?? ?????? ??? ????? ??? ??????? ?? ????? ???? ??? ?????`

if page in `windows-1251`, but text in `utf-8` you see this:
`"РњРѕР±РёР»СЊРЅС‹Рµ С‚РµР»РµС„РѕРЅС‹";"Apple iPhone 4`

Comment: That text was from XML file and problem was only with html tags.

Answer (score 0):

I always use manual convertation (character-by-character), like this:

```
$input= 'РћР±СЂР°С‰РµРЅРёРµ РљР°С';



$s= str_replace('С?','fgr43443443',$input);
$s= mb_convert_encoding($s, "windows-1251", "utf-8");
$s= str_replace('fgr43443443','ш',$s);


echo $s;
```

p.s. dont forget, the .php file encoding should be UTF8.
also, in the head of HTML,insert  standard declaration for **UTF8**

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the solutions lack  conversion to single-byte  encoding.
I use mb_convert_encoding($string,'windows-1251') to convert  from UTF-8  in my  case.

```
function ru2Lat($string)
{
$rus = array('ё','ж','ц','ч','ш','щ','ю','я','Ё','Ж','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ю','Я');
$lat = array('yo','zh','tc','ch','sh','sh','yu','ya','YO','ZH','TC','CH','SH','SH','YU','YA');
$string = str_replace($rus,$lat,$string);
$string = strtr($string,
     "АБВГДЕЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЪЫЬЭабвгдезийклмнопрстуфхъыьэ",
     "ABVGDEZIJKLMNOPRSTUFH_I_Eabvgdezijklmnoprstufh'i'e");

return($string);
}

function transliterate($string){
    if (!is_string($string)) return $string;
    return ru2lat(mb_convert_encoding($string,'windows-1251'));
}

function transliterate_array($a){

$c = array_map(transliterate,$a);
             return $c;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, "utf-8", "windows-1251");
$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, "windows-1251", "Windows-1250");

//works to me

Answer (score -3):

try this, works for me!

```
$result = str_replace ('Â€', 'â‚¬' , $result);
```

Comment: How is this better than the accepted answer from four years ago?