# PHP Convert win-1251 to UTF-8 is not working

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have source string (received from mail body)

> =C7=E4=F0=E0=E2=F1=F2=E2=F3=E9=F2=E5

[Online decoder](http://www.online-decoder.com) says it Windows-1251 encoding and successfully convert it to UTF-8. **mb_detect_encoding** says it ASCII

I need to convert via PHP. I tried **mb_convert_encoding** and **iconv**, solution from stackoverflow ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8) and [one more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706077/php-convert-windows-1251-to-utf-8)) and many others. But there is no result. Source string is not changed.

Maybe you know working solution? Thank you.

Comment: What is your source string? and what is your goal? how should the string looks at the end?

Comment: @Rizier123 My string is cyrillic. I need to convert it to Unicode. Result string is "Здравствуйте".

Comment: okay your result is "Здравствуйте" and what you expect to be?

Comment: @Rizier123 Unicode string

Comment: so you want `=C7=E4=F0=E0=E2=F1=F2=E2=F3=E9=F2=E5` to turn into `Здравствуйте`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you could try apply `iconv()` in this case:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$string = '=C7=E4=F0=E0=E2=F1=F2=E2=F3=E9=F2=E5';
$string = str_replace('=', '%', $string);
$string = rawurldecode($string);
$string = iconv('Windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $string);
echo $string; // Здравствуйте
```

Comment: One more question? Maybe exists alternative for using str_replace? If source string contains "=", it can be corrupted

Comment: @indapublic i'l get back to you in just a sec, maybe theres a better way to handle this